# Can't get text to wrap around video

Tags: html, css

I'my trying to get my video to float on the right , but can't get the text to wrap around it. Any suggestions? I've tried putting a float on both the surrounding text and the video but to no avail!

```
<video controls width="360" poster="../images/video.jpg" style="float:right;">
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42hst8d5/

Comment: Could just update the order the html is in: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/42hst8d5/1/

Comment: You should really only post the necessary code in your JSFiddle. Nobody wants to comb through your code to find where your issue is.

Comment: And you should **always** post your code in your question. Highlighting random text as code to get past the warning you saw doesn't cut it.

Comment: @j08691 I agree with you completely but I'm the one that highlighted the random text to get past the warning on my edit. That said he should still be posting code.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Well, his original question had random text highlighted as well. You just randomly highlighted other text and it wasn't a valid edit...

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex fair point. I should have put some code from his jsfiddle in at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `<p>`aragraph tags in a `<section>` with some kind of class on it. `float` your section left and then `float` the video left as well. Make sure the video is not inside the `section` tags. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/42hst8d5/

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. I'm not seeing the text wrapping around the video.

Comment: My mistake, I was just working on getting the float to happen and get them side by side. I hadn't fully understood the questions. This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hab2s7zu/ more correctly answers the question. Adding the video inside the paragraph tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<video>` element is below all your text. In order to have the text float around it, put the video above or within the `<p>` tags:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat accumsan lacus sed lacinia. Vestibulum ac leo nisl. Fusce porttitor sollicitudin fermentum. Nam vulputate quis dui in faucibus. Donec congue in urna a ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum odio metus, faucibus quis vulputate eu, tristique vitae ipsum. Morbi sagittis mi tincidunt sagittis congue. Donec a aliquam ex. Vivamus lacinia mollis ante ut suscipit. Donec condimentum interdum lorem. In scelerisque metus euismod, aliquet nulla a, rutrum nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
<video ...></video>
<p>Sed justo massa, suscipit non pulvinar a, auctor vel felis. Aliquam pretium sem et est tincidunt, sit amet volutpat turpis malesuada. Suspendisse efficitur sollicitudin tellus, nec eleifend leo. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum magna odio, laoreet a mattis a, hendrerit viverra leo. Nulla facilisi. Ut consequat suscipit velit. Nulla bibendum, velit quis dapibus scelerisque, ligula nisi faucibus turpis, vitae tristique urna lorem in nunc.</p>
```

See updated http://jsfiddle.net/d9doczjn/